# Y-axis labels in the bar chart should be different

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, bar-chart

I want to have three different Y-axes labels for the three bar-charts shown below. To reiterate, the labels should be N=3,N=6,N=12,N=24,N=48 for the bar-chart (a) MADDPG and N=1,N=10,N=20,N=30,N=50 for (b) MATD3, and N=1,N=25,N=50,N=75,N=100 for MASAC

**My code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.7pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size=3 by 1, horizontal sep=1.2cm}, 
width=0.3\textwidth, height=0.3cm,
xmajorgrids=true,
tick align=outside, xtick pos=left,
scale only axis,
x post scale=0.85,
enlarge y limits=0.20,
xmin=0, xmax=100,
xtick={0,20,...,100},
ytick=data, yticklabels={N=3,N=6,N=12,N=24,N=48},
xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},
xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
yticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, xshift=3pt},
nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize,  yshift=8pt},
legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south, legend columns=4, font=\footnotesize, cells={anchor=west}},
xbar stacked,
/pgf/bar width=2.5mm,
y=5.2mm,
legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.2cm);
            },
title style={at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north},
nodes near coords={\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=0}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
%coordinate style/.condition={x-0.5*rawx<5}{red, xshift=4pt},
coordinate style/.condition={x-0.5*rawx>95}{xshift=-4pt},
]

\nextgroupplot[title=(a) MADDPG]
\addplot [color=black, pattern color=black, pattern=crosshatch dots, %
nodes near coords={\pgfmathparse{less(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed,100)}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
\hspace{8pt}%
\fi%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=0}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}]
coordinates{(43,1) (30,2) (20,3) (12,4) (4,5)};
%\addplot [color=black,  pattern color=gray, pattern=checkerboard] 
%coordinates{(16.57,1) (39.97,2) (56.37,3) (0,4)};
\addplot [color=black,  pattern color=gray, pattern=checkerboard] coordinates{(55,1) (68,2)(79,3) (88,4) (96,5)};
\addplot [color=black,  pattern color=black, pattern=north west lines] coordinates{(2,1) (2,2) (1,3) (1,4) (0,5)};
%4
\nextgroupplot[title=(b) MATD3]
\addplot [color=black,  pattern color=black, pattern=crosshatch dots, %
nodes near coords={\pgfmathparse{less(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed,100)}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
\hspace{8pt}%
\fi%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/precision=0}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}]
coordinates{(45,1) (31,2) (18,3) (10,4) (3,5)};
% \addplot [color=black, pattern color=gray, pattern=checkerboard] 
% coordinates{(22,1) (36,2) (50.12,3) (0,4)};
\addplot [color=black,  pattern color=gray, pattern=checkerboard] 
coordinates{(53,1) (67,2) (81,3) (90,4) (97,5)};
\addplot [color=black, pattern color=black, pattern=north west lines] 
coordinates{(2,1) (2,2) (1,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\legend{Action selection, Update all trainers, Other Parts},
%3,4

\nextgroupplot[title=(c) MASAC]
\addplot [color=black,  pattern color=black, pattern=crosshatch dots]
coordinates{(52,1) (45,2) (38,3) (26,4) (13,5)};
% \addplot [color=black, pattern color=gray, pattern=checkerboard] 
% coordinates{(21,1) (36,2) (51,3) (0,4)};
\addplot [color=black,   pattern color=gray, pattern=checkerboard] coordinates{(46,1) (53,2)(62,3) (74,4) (87,5)};
\addplot [color=black, pattern color=black, pattern=north west lines] 
coordinates{(2,1) (2,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
% %3,4

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\caption{Training time breakdown for three MARL workloads with 3, 6, 12 \& 24 agents. The environment is Competitive task~(Predator-Prey).}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem? :)

Comment: What you mean with "be different"? You prescribe, that should be equal in each diagram. Please clarify!

Comment: Hello, just edited the question to better understand it!

Comment: Than prescribe them locally at each diagram,

Comment: @zarko, I've tried inserting the y labels locally. But it doesn't show me any difference. I don't know if I'm inserting the at the correct position. Can you point me to the location in the code where I should insert it locally to each bar chart? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

I took a liberty (and some my sparse time in night) and rewrite your MWE to more concise and clear (at least to me) form. You may liked it :

```
\documentclass[journal,compsoc,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
    \raggedright
\begin{tikzpicture}[
patt-A/.style = {pattern={Dots[angle=45, distance=2pt,xshift=1pt]},
                 pattern color=#1},
patt-B/.style = {pattern=checkerboard,
                 pattern color=#1},
patt-C/.style = {pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=2pt]},
                 pattern color=#1},
                    ]
    \begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group size=3 by 1,
    horizontal sep=12mm
            },
    width=0.33\linewidth,
    enlarge y limits=0.2,
%
    xmajorgrids=true,
    tick align=outside, 
%
    title style={at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north},
%
    xbar stacked,
    /pgf/bar width=2.5mm,
    y=6mm,
%
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    xtick distance=20,
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    ytick=data,
%   
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%
                   },
coordinate style/.condition={x-0.5*rawx<11}{xshift=+2pt},
coordinate style/.condition={x-0.5*rawx>95}{xshift=-4pt},
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=1.6ex},
%
legend image code/.code={\draw[#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.4cm,0.1cm);},
legend style={at={(0.5,1.05)}, anchor=south,
              legend columns=-1,
              font=\scriptsize,
              /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1em}
              },
]

\nextgroupplot[
    title=(a) MADDPG,
    yticklabels={N=3,N=6,N=12,N=24,N=48},
                ]
\addplot [patt-A=gray]    coordinates{(43,1) (30,2) (20,3) (12,4) (4,5)};
\addplot [patt-B=gray]    coordinates{(55,1) (68,2) (79,3) (88,4) (96,5)};
\addplot [patt-C=black]   coordinates{(2,1)  (2,2)  (1,3)  (1,4)  (0,5)};

\nextgroupplot[
    title=(b) MATD3,
    yticklabels={N=1,N=10,N=20,N=30,N=50}
                ]
\addplot [patt-A=gray]
    coordinates{(45,1) (31,2) (18,3) (10,4) (3,5)};
\addplot [patt-B=gray]
    coordinates{(53,1) (67,2) (81,3) (90,4) (97,5)};
\addplot [patt-C=black]
    coordinates{(2,1) (2,2) (1,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\legend{Action selection, Update all trainers, Other Parts},

\nextgroupplot[
    title=(c) MASAC,
    yticklabels={N=3,N=25,N=50,N=75,N=100},    
                ]
\addplot [patt-A=black]
    coordinates{(52,1) (45,2) (38,3) (26,4) (13,5)};
\addplot [patt-B=gray]
    coordinates{(46,1) (53,2)(62,3) (74,4) (87,5)};
\addplot [patt-C=gray]
    coordinates{(2,1) (2,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Training time breakdown for three MARL workloads with 3, 6, 12 \& 24 agents. The environment is Competitive task~(Predator-Prey).}
\label{figure1}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help!! Really appreciate it.